# cant repeat same section using HTML, shows only 1 block of code and ignore the other

Tags: html

I have a section that contains image slider in an HTML page, I want to repeat it but the 2nd one never appears. here is the original code

```
  <!-- Featured Listings Start -->
    <section class="featured-lis">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
                    <h3 class="section-title">Featured Listings</h3>
                    <div id="new-products" class="owl-carousel">
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="product-item">
                                <div class="carousel-thumb">
                                    <img src="{% static './assets/img/product/img1.jpg' %}" alt="">
                                    <div class="overlay">
                                        <a href="ads-details.html"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <a href="ads-details.html" class="item-name">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</a>
                                <span class="price">$150</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="product-item">
                                <div class="carousel-thumb">
                                    <img src="{% static './assets/img/product/img2.jpg' %}" alt="">
                                    <div class="overlay">
                                        <a href="ads-details.html"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <a href="ads-details.html" class="item-name">Sed diam nonummy</a>
                                <span class="price">$67</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="product-item">
                                <div class="carousel-thumb">
                                    <img src="{% static './assets/img/product/img3.jpg' %}" alt="">
                                    <div class="overlay">
                                        <a href="ads-details.html"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <a href="ads-details.html" class="item-name">Feugiat nulla facilisis</a>
                                <span class="price">$300</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="product-item">
                                <div class="carousel-thumb">
                                    <img src="{% static './assets/img/product/img4.jpg' %}" alt="">
                                    <div class="overlay">
                                        <a href="ads-details.html"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <a href="ads-details.html" class="item-name">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</a>
                                <span class="price">$149</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="product-item">
                                <div class="carousel-thumb">
                                    <img src="{% static './assets/img/product/img5.jpg' %}" alt="">
                                    <div class="overlay">
                                        <a href="ads-details.html"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <a href="ads-details.html" class="item-name">Sed diam nonummy</a>
                                <span class="price">$90</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="product-item">
                                <div class="carousel-thumb">
                                    <img src="{% static './assets/img/product/img6.jpg' %}" alt="">
                                    <div class="overlay">
                                        <a href="ads-details.html"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <a href="ads-details.html" class="item-name">Praesent luptatum zzril</a>
                                <span class="price">$169</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="product-item">
                                <div class="carousel-thumb">
                                    <img src="{% static './assets/img/product/img7.jpg' %}" alt="">
                                    <div class="overlay">
                                        <a href="ads-details.html"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <a href="ads-details.html" class="item-name">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</a>
                                <span class="price">$79</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="product-item">
                                <div class="carousel-thumb">
                                    <img src="{% static './assets/img/product/img8.jpg' %}" alt="">
                                    <div class="overlay">
                                        <a href="ads-details.html"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <a href="ads-details.html" class="item-name">Sed diam nonummy</a>
                                <span class="price">$149</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Featured Listings End -->
```

All what i did is repeating this whole block of code once again , to have 2 slider in the page ... but it didn't show the 2nd one .
Leaving it as its shown in the code works great showing only 1 single slider. the problem only appears when i repeat the code once again to have 2 block of codes . only 1 slider appear.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: oh Thank you , didn't notice that at all, add it as an answer to accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure when you duplicate your blocks of code that you keep all of your IDs unique. Duplicating them is what's causing the issue.